# Use of Ajax , Jquery and ,javascript for Phonegap Applications

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova

While wandering in the world of phonegap mobile application development, I am using a number of web services calls. To call the web services, I have used Ajax and Jquery.

In the JavaScript file, I have written a number of ajax functions. When I am getting a result, I display that in the html page using the following:

```
document.getElementById('demos').innerHTML = content;
```

But the thing is that, **I am unable to apply Jquery for scrolling the content of a DIV tag.**

Can you give some references or hint to get out of it?

Comment: when I write that code from normal function(not $ajax success), then I got it correct.means with scrollable view

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I recommend using iscroll4.js http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4 to implement horizontal and vertical scrolling for DIVs. The website has several nice examples that you can try, and then you can inspect the code to see how it is done. I have used this on a Phonegap app.

Secondly, consider using XUI or Zepto to replace Jquery. Even JQuery Mobile is a bit more than you really need for a mobile app. In fact, I try to make do with just dLite http://code.google.com/p/dlite/ and then add only the extra bits that I really need.

Comment: A Michael said above, use iScroll4. Then after you load your ajax content, make sure to refresh the scull object so that it knows the new height.